# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.DateTime?' to 'System.DateTime' in LINQ query

Tags: c#, mysql, linq

I'm trying to pull in data from my MySQL database and then group the results using LINQ, but I'm getting the error *"Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.DateTime?' to 'System.DateTime'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)"*.

My data mostly consists of strings but there are a few DateTime columns that are obviously the cause of the issue. Suggestions in other threads don't seem to use LINQ but I wondered if it's possible to solve this in my LINQ query?

Here's a snippet of my code, where the Items list is populated from iterating my db:

```
List<dynamic> Items = new List<dynamic>();

var items = from t in Items
    group t by t.Name into g
    select new
    {
        Name = g.FirstOrDefault().Name,
        DateOnSale = g.FirstOrDefault().DateOnSale
    };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DateOnSale = g.FirstOrDefault().DateOnSale.GetValueOrDefault()
```